# Store column value as parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net

When the button is clicked I need to find and store value of column ObjID for that row.
Table:

https://jsfiddle.net/qmg1309n/2/

This is the C# part where I send the value to from procedure to grid view:

```
LogicTableAdapters.getLevelTableAdapter getLvl = new LogicTableAdapters.getLevelTableAdapter();

DataTable dtLvl = getLvl.getLevel(Convert.ToInt32(ddlLevel.SelectedValue));

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[4]{ new DataColumn("ObjtID", typeof(int)), new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)), new DataColumn("BCC", typeof(string)),new DataColumn("ParentName", typeof(string))  ,});
foreach (DataRow dr in dtLvl.Rows)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dr["ObjID"]), dr["Name"].ToString(), dr["BCC"].ToString(), dr["ParentName"].ToString());
}

gvObject.DataSource = dt;
gvObject.DataBind();
```

This is the asp part where everything is generated:

```
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <button class="myBtn" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="vertical-align: middle"><span>Select</span></button>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ObjID">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="ObjID" runat="server" class="ObjekatID" Width="118px" Height="36px" Style="text-align: center" Font-Names="Georgia" margin-Left="100px" Text='<%# Bind("ObjID") %>'></asp:Label>


        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
        <ItemTemplate>

            <asp:Label ID="Name" runat="server" Width="118px" Height="26px" Style="text-align: center" Font-Names="Georgia" margin-Left="100px" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Label>

        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BCC">
        <ItemTemplate>

            <asp:Label ID="BCC" runat="server" Width="118px" Height="26px" Style="text-align: center" Font-Names="Georgia" margin-Left="100px" Text='<%# Bind("BCC") %>'></asp:Label>

        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ParentName">
        <ItemTemplate>

            <asp:Label ID="ParentName" runat="server" Width="118px" Height="26px" Style="text-align: center" Font-Names="Georgia" margin-Left="100px" Text='<%# Bind("ParentName") %>'></asp:Label>

        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

I need to store column value as a variable so I could use it later as a parameter to generate new grid view when the button is clicked. I will use similar code for this, only another procedure.

```
getLvl.getLevel(Convert.ToInt32(ddlLevel.SelectedValue));
```

And isnsted of ddlLevel:SelectedValue the variable that contains a paramether(value of column taken when button is clicked).

I tried using ajax and webmethod but I had some problems, because frist gridview is populated and that ajax is read everytime so I will need some other way.
Can someone help me please?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
1. Your Select Button code --> <asp:Button ID="Button2"  runat="server" CausesValidation="false" Text="Select" CommandName="GetRec"></asp:Button>  

    public void gvObject_OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "GetRec")
        {
            Label lblName = (Label)gvObject.FindControl("Name");
            Label lblBCC = (Label)gvObject.FindControl("BCC");
        }
    }
```

Use OnRowCommand Event of gridview. 
String BCC = lblBCC.Text;
Hope this will help you:-)

Answer (score 1):

Add event for buttоn `On_Click` аnd thеn usе:

```
protected void Selectbtn_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    var ObjectIdValue = ((Label)(((sender as LinkButton).NamingContainer as GridViewRow)
        .FindControl("ObjIDLbl"))).Text;
}
```

Comment: I get this error :/

An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WebApplication.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.